# SQL query on Union and Left Join

Tags: sql-server, union

I have this query

```
SELECT 
    fc.ID AS FileCategoryId
    ,fc.FolderCategoryName as FileCategoryName
    ,fcparent.ID AS FileParentCategoryID
    ,fcparent.FolderCategoryName AS FileParentName
    ,FileAllowView = 0
    ,FileAllowDownload = 0
    ,FileCategoryType = 0
FROM 
    FolderCategory AS fc 
    LEFT JOIN FolderCategory AS fcparent ON fc.FolderParentCategoryId = fcparent.ID

UNION

SELECT 
    f.ID as FileCategoryId 
    ,f.FileName as FileCategoryName
    ,f.FolderCategoryId as FileParentCategoryId
    ,ffcparent.FolderCategoryName AS FileParentName
    ,FileAllowView = (Case when fp.AllowView IS Null Then 1 ELSE fp.AllowView END)
    ,FileAllowDownload = (Case when fp.AllowDownload IS Null Then 1 ELSE fp.AllowDownload END)
    ,FileCategoryType = 1
FROM 
    [dbo].Files as f
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].FolderCategory as ffcparent ON f.FolderCategoryId = ffcparent.ID
    LEFT JOIN FilePermissions as fp ON  f.ID = fp.FileId
Where FileAllowView = 1
```

But it gives me Invalid column name "FileAllowView" but i declared it the column. Please help me on this one.

Comment: Where clause executed before Select clause. And you have define FileAllowView in select clause, So, Where clause has no idea about What is FileAllowView.

Comment: Instead of FileAllowView in Where clause, Use >> where (Case when fp.AllowView IS Null Then 1 ELSE fp.AllowView END) = 1

Comment: Also you can `WHERE fp.AllowView IS Null`

Answer (score 0):

Update your `WHERE` condition as below, in your current condition you have applied where logic on column (FileAllowView) which not exist in scope. Instead new column you can apply where condition with your initial column `fp.AllowView`

I have convert to `BIT`, if it `INTEGER` value then convert it to `INT`

```
Where CAST(ISNULL(fp.AllowView,1) AS BIT) = 1
```

OR

```
Where (fp.AllowView=1 OR fp.AllowView IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per logical procedings in SQL the WHERE clause is executed first and later comes to the SELECT clause but you had mentioned the new column in the SELECT clause thats the reason why the SQL server throws an error when it try to execute the WHERE clause with unknown Column in the Table, try to modify the WHERE clause according to your condition but not with the Aliasing name.